# Configure consul for dynamic health check services

Tags: python, consul

I have a consul stack with 2 hosts (for testing). 1 host only run consul in bootstrap mode and the other one run client mode with Registrator for automatically registering services (both run on docker). And now, if I start an application (port 8080 for example) container, Registrator will detect then register it to consul, but it does not have http-check as I want. I found that Registrator has option for auto register health check is add `SERVICE_8080_CHECK_HTTP: '/'` to application container, it work pretty good. At this point I have a problem, if I `docker stop` application container, there is no health check for this app so I can't get the status to write some stuff for alert or replace failed app. So the question is, how can I got dynamic health check services but still get status `passing or failed or warning or critical`
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registrator de-registers the service when you stop the container. If you have multiple instances of that service it shouldn't be a problem.

If this is your use-case after all, don't use Registrator for service registration, you can use Consul's HTTP API to register the service or include a service definition file for the agent.

In any case, uou really shouldn't run a single Consul server - https://www.consul.io/intro/index.html